# Why does Crypto Street have backwards pairs?

Tags: exchanges, currencies, exchange-rate

I'm looking at the crypto street home page and the pairs are backwards when compared to other exchanges. It doesn't appear to be a mistake because the prices are inverted compared to other exchanges - it just seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the CEO of [Crypto Street](http://www.crypto.st), so let's get that out of the way. I recently wrote a [blog post](https://www.crypto.st/blog/2013/08/btc-ltc-vs-ltc-btc) about this explaining. But the gist of it is that we're taking a page from standard financial markets:

> In the foreign exchange market, currencies are displayed as what's
>   known as a currency pair. Trades require that one currency be
>   exchanged for another, in proportion to the quoted pair. As an
>   example, let's consider USD/JPY, which at the time of this post is
>   98.74. What that means is that to buy 1 USD, you will need to give 98.74 JPY. Generally speaking, the stronger currency is quoted first so that one can easily understand how many of the quote currency one
>   will need to buy the base currency. If we reveresed it, and instead
>   quoted JPY/USD, it would mean that to buy 1 JPY I would need to give
>   0.01012760785902 USD. That's a lot harder to intuitively grasp than 98.74!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the notation is inconsistent with, well, math. If you say 98 USD/JPY, it looks like 98 USD per 1 JPY.

That said, this is also an issue on Bloomberg or Yahoo or any financial reporting site that I know of.